# AngularJS: How to target specific directive with multiple instances

Tags: angularjs

I have multiple instances of a directive and I would like to target a specific instance only.  For example in the code below, how can I make sure that the div with `class="one"` is the only one that gets triggered by the event `$rootScope.$broadcast('myEvent')`.

JS:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: function(scope, el, attrs) {
            scope.$on('myEvent', function() {
                el.css({left: '+=100'});
            });
        },
    };    
});
```

HTML:

```
<div my-directive class="one"></div>
<div my-directive class="two"></div>
```

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible, since it is a broadcast all the child scopes will get the event notification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do this check in your event handler:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
      controller: function(scope, el, attrs) {
        scope.$on('myEvent', function(ev,args) {
          //do the check - you could provide a function, a value or something else
          if(el.hasClass(args.class)){
            el.css({left: '+=100'});
          }
        });
      },
  };    
});
```

Then add the parameters in the $broadcast

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('myEvent',{class:'one'})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define a new attribute for this directive which references a callback that then is executed inside the callback of $on:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
          callme: "="
        },
        controller: function(scope, el, attrs) {
            scope.$on('myEvent', function() {
                scope.callme(el)
            });
        },
    };    
});
```

HTML declaration:

```
<div my-directive class="one" callme="functionDefinedInScope"></div>
```

In your Controller scope:

```
$scope.functionDefinedInScope = function(el) {
    el.css({left: '+=100'});
}
```

Read more about this here:
http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive (Section "Directive Definition Object")

Comment: This might not work for my case. I forgot to mention that I could be targeting any one of the directives at different times.

Answer (score 0):

can you use id instead of class

```
<div my-directive id="one"></div>
<div my-directive id="two"></div>
```

and in your controller

```
controller: function(scope, el, attrs) {
   scope.moveElement = function() {
      el.css({left: '+=100'});
   }
}
```

and then instead of broadcast,

```
angular.element('#one').scope().moveElement()
```